# $K=span\{x_i,x_2,\dots ,x_k\}$, $X$ is orthonormal, then $\{y_{k+1},y_{k+2},\dots y_n\}$ is a basis for $K^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a problem from final exam in my university. I think, the problem was quite hard. I can't answer the question.

Let $V$ be inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$, $\dim V\geq 2$ and $X$ be a basis for $V$. Let non singular $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and $B=(A^{-1})^*$. For $i=1,2,\dots n$ consider the $i$-th column of matrices $A$ and $B$ as coordinate vector $x_i$ and $y_i$ in $V$ with basis $X$. Let $K=span\{x_i,x_2,\dots ,x_k\}$ for some $k$, $1,\leq k<n$.

a. Show that if $X$ is orthonormal, then $\{y_{k+1},y_{k+2},\dots y_n\}$ is a basis for $K^{\perp}$

b. If  $\{y_{k+1},y_{k+2},\dots y_n\}$ is a basis for $K^{\perp}$, check whether $K$ is orthonormal or not

Comment: I think this:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra is related, but I am not 100% of how. Just to make sure, $(A^{-1})*$ is the vector space dual?

Comment: @user99680 I think $(A^{-1})^*$ means the adjoint of the matrix.

Comment: @Brandon:  I think you're right, thanks.

Comment: What is $x_i$? The $i$-column of $A$ or the $i$-th vector in the basis $X$ or both?

Comment: Also, is K a set (basis) or a space? If a subspace, what do you mean by $K$ being orthonormal?